# Best way to solve race condition on DataBase

Tags: c#, sql-server, multithreading, race-condition

I have an application that saves captions for a movie.
I need to prevent a scenario where 2 captions are overlapping.
First I will define what is overlapping captions.
Let's assume that caption class has MovieId,EntryTime,ExistTime andText.
The EntryTime is a number that represents in which time (in milliseconds) into the movie the caption is shown and the ExistTime is the time into the movie where it will disappear. 
If we have 2 captions as follow

```
var caption1 = new Caption(){MovieId = 1, EntryTime = 100, ExistTime =200}
var caption2 = new Caption(){MovieId = 1, EntryTime = 120, ExistTime =220}
```

They are overlapping, but the following captions are not

```
var caption3 = new Caption(){MovieId = 1, EntryTime = 400, ExistTime =450}
var caption4 = new Caption(){MovieId = 2, EntryTime = 425, ExistTime =470}
```

All captions for all movies are saved in the same database with the same table in the database.

In order to avoid inserting overlapping captions, I first try to put a lock in my server code. This code checks specifically the EntryTime and EndTime of a caption and does not check the overlapping scenario, but this check should support the overlapping case

```
  lock (insertCaptionLocker)
                    {
                        var captionExists = dbCaptions.Captions.Any(x =>
                                x.MovieId == caption.MovieId && x.EntryTime == caption.EntryTime &&
                                x.ExitTime == caption.ExitTime);

                        if (!captionExists)
                        {

                            dbCaptions.Captions.InsertOnSubmit(caption);
                        }

                        dbCaptions.SubmitChanges();
                    }
```

I have a few problems with this code:

1. It's not always a critical section - most of the time its should be ok to allow more than 1 thread to enter this code. only if we have 2 threads (or more) that trying to update for the same MovieId with overlapping times we have a problem.
2. It won't work if we have more than 1 server connected with a load balancer.

I think that the solution should come from the database in some way but I don't what to use.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Does http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/SQLPreventRangeOverlap.aspx help?

Comment: Where should the next caption start? For example, if a caption ends at 200, should the next caption start at 201, or 200? Should gaps also be permissable? So, if a caption starts at 0 and ends at 100, and then the next is created at 150, is that allowed?

Comment: Its allowed - for now we don't have a minimum gap between captions

Comment: And the start/end?

Comment: @Larnu 
I'm not sure I understand your question. All captions for a movie are sorted in chronological order, so the following is Ok 
[100-200] [205-300][301-400] etc, but this is not valid : [100-200][150-225][300-4] Hope I answer your question :-)

Comment: Yes, but is `[100-200][200-300][305-400]` ok, or should it be `[101-200][201-300][305-400]`? As I asked before.

Comment: it should be [101-200][201-300][305-400]

Answer (score 0):

An observation:

Your condition checks only if, for a given MovieId, there already exist a caption with same EntryTime and ExistTime, it doesn't check if they overlap.

for non-overlap you should check something like this, checking the start and
finish time for every pair:

```
var non_overlapping = dbCaptions.Captions.Any(x =>
x.MovieId == caption.MovieId &&( x.EntryTime < caption.EntryTime && x.ExitTime < caption.EntryTime || x.EntryTime > caption.EntryTime && caption.ExitTime < x.EntryTime )
```

This pairs will be non-overlapping, so you can insert them.
With your approach you will just get the exact same captions, but not all the ones that overlap, ypu coul also define a range and check if your tuple `(x.EntryTime ,x.ExitTime)` is in the `range(caption.EntryTime ,caption.ExitTime)`.

Comment: Thank you,
I wrote that the real query (the one in my code) is different from what I wrote, It was only for simplicity, but thank you for noticing

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice. In any case, i think that if you cannot make the db insert code work with your load balancing layer, you could try doing it at db level with a INSTEAD OF trigger, in your case it will be INSTEAD OF INSERT, this way you can try to implement your condition directly at the database level.